# Pygame programs hanging on exit

Tags: python, pygame

I'm tinkering around with pygame right now, and it seems like all the little programs that I make with it hang when I try to close them.

Take the following code, for example:

```
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
# YEEAAH!
tile_file = "blue_tile.bmp"
SCREEN_SIZE = (640, 480)
SCREEN_DEPTH = 32

if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE, 0, SCREEN_DEPTH)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                break

    tile = pygame.image.load(tile_file).convert()
    colorkey = tile.get_at((0,0))
    tile.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)

    y = SCREEN_SIZE[1] / 2
    x = SCREEN_SIZE[0] / 2

    for _ in xrange(50):
        screen.blit(tile, (x,y))
        x -= 7
        y -= 14
```

I don't see anything wrong with the code, it works (ignore the fact that the tile isn't blit in the right spots), but there's no traceback and the only way to close it is to kill the python process in Task Manager. Can anyone spot a problem with my code?

Answer (score 13):

If you are running it from IDLE, then you are missing **pygame.quit()**.

> This is caused by the IDLE python interpreter, which seems to keep the references around somehow. Make sure, you invoke pygame.quit() on exiting your application or game.

See: [In IDLE why does the Pygame window not close correctly?](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#In%20IDLE%20why%20does%20the%20Pygame%20window%20not%20close%20correctly?)

And also: [Pygame Documentation - pygame.quit()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit)

Answer (score 12):

Where do you exit the outer loop?

```
 while True: # outer loop
     for event in pygame.event.get(): # inner loop
         if event.type == QUIT:
            break # <- break inner loop
```

Comment: Yeah, the structure of the program seems broken. I am quite surprised that such a program would produce any output at all. In fact, I suspect this is the OP's actual code.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but solved it by doing the following:

```
try:
   while True:
      for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type==QUIT or pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_ESCAPE]:
            pygame.quit()
            break
finally:
   pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

'if event.type==QUIT' generates a syntax error. Should be == pygame.QUIT
Also, the rest of the line is incorrect but I can't see how.
There's a cleaner variant [here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-physics-simulation/creating-pygame-window):

```
    running = True
    while running:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           running = False
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: With `from pygame.locals import *`, the OP has `QUIT` in the global namespace so there's no syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on knowing why I can't close pygame windows.. and searched.. and came across this..

I think this explains everything.. and good idea too..

as seen in: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/802028-pygame-window-not-closing-tut-not-helping

> I think the issue is that you're
>   running it from within IDLE. It looks
>   like pyGame's event loop and Tkinter's
>   event loop interfere with each other.
>   If you run the scripts from the
>   command line, it works.

Comment: It can be run in IDLE, but the code needs slight modifications