# Where's the error in this simple pygame program? (sys.exit() not working)

Tags: python, sys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pygame programs hanging on exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027105/pygame-programs-hanging-on-exit)

Ran this simple program:

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

while True:
    #process input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                sys.exit()
```

Got this simple message in IDLE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aerovistae/Desktop/GD_in_class", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit()
SystemExit
```

And the program stops responding and has to be Ctrl+Alt+Del'd. I can't see where I'm going wrong here, this is as basic as I can get. I was following what a professor did in lecture, I don't see any difference between my code and his. Can anyone suggest what might cause the problem?

Comment: Check this question: [pygame programs hanging on exit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027105/pygame-programs-hanging-on-exit) This may refer to a problem with IDLE, try it without it.

Comment: I don't know pygame, but what I remember from wxpython is that sometimes if you exit the python program with `sys.exit()` there are 'traces' of the wxwidgets left behind (sounds vague, don't know if true or how to better explain). You should see if there's a way to stop pygame. (`pygame.close()` or something like that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper way to quit pygame is to call

`pygame.quit()`

after the main run loop.

Read From the pygame documentation: [http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#In IDLE why does the Pygame window not close correctly?](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#In%20IDLE%20why%20does%20the%20Pygame%20window%20not%20close%20correctly?)

Just exit the main run loop instead of sys.exit() and end the program.